# What is the number of columns that make table really big?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have two tables in my database, one for login and second for user details (the database is not only two tables). Logins table has 12 columns (Id, Email, Password, PhoneNumber ...) and user details has 23 columns (Job, City, Gender, ContactInfo ..). The two tables have one-to-one relationship.

I am thinking to create one table that contain the columns of both tables but I not sure because this may make the size of the table big.

So this lead to my question, what the number of columns that make table big? Is there a certain or approximate number that make size of table big and make us stop adding columns to a table and create another one? or it is up to the programmer to decide such number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of columns isn't realistically a problem. Any kind of performance issues you seem to be worried with can be attributed to the size of the DATA on the table. Ie, if the table has billions of rows, or if one of the columns contains 200 MB of XML data on each separate row, etc.

Normally, the only issue arising from a multitude of columns is how it pertains to indexing, as it can get troublesome trying to create 100 different indexes covering each variation of each query.

Point here is, we can't really give you any advice since just the number of tables and columns and relations isn't enough information to go on. It could be perfectly fine, or not. The nature of the data, and how you account for that data with proper normalization, indexing and statistics, is what really matters.

Answer (score 2):

The constraint that makes us stop adding columns to an existing table in SQL is if we exceed the maximum number of columns that the database engine can support for a single table. As can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), for SQLServer that is 1024 columns for a non-wide table, or 30,000 columns for a wide table.

35 columns is not a particularly large number of columns for a table.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why decomposing a table (splitting up by columns) might be advisable.  One of the first reasons a beginner should learn is data normalization.  Data normalization is not directly concerned with performance, although a normalized database will sometimes outperform a poorly built one, especially under load.

The first three steps in normalization result in 1st, 2nd, and 3rd normal forms.  These forms have to do with the relationship that non-key values have to the key.  A simple summary is that a table in 3rd normal form is one where all the non-key values are determined by the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.

There is a whole body of literature out there that will teach you how to normalize, what the benefits of normalization are, and what the drawbacks sometimes are.  Once you become proficient in normalization, you may wish to learn when to depart from the normalization rules, and follow a design pattern like Star Schema, which results in a well structured, but not normalized design.

Some people treat normalization like a religion, but that's overselling the idea.  It's definitely a good thing to learn, but it's only a set of guidelines that can often (but not always) lead you in the direction of a satisfactory design.

A normalized database tends to outperform a non normalized one at update time, but a denormalized database can be built that is extraordinarily speedy for certain kinds of retrieval.

And, of course, all this depends on how many databases you are going to build, and their size and scope,

Comment: The two tables have one-to-one relationship

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the login tables contains data that is only used when the user logs into your system. For all other purposes, the details table is used.

Separating these sets of data into separate tables is not a bad idea and could work perfectly well for your application. However, another option is having the data in one table and separating them using covering indexes.

One aspect of an index no one seems to consider is that an index can be thought of as a sub-table within a table. When a SQL statement accesses only the fields within an index, the I/O required to perform the operation can be limited to only the index rather than the entire row. So creating a "login" index and "details" index would achieve the same benefits as separate tables. With the added benefit that any operations that do need all the data would not have to perform a join of two tables.